# how to add response image data from 1st ViewController to NextViewController in uicollectionview in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to add response image data from 1st ViewController to NextViewController in uicollectionview in objectiveC

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBs1h.png)

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

    return drinklist.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: your question is how to pass data from one controller to next . Please google it once you will get a solution.

Comment: Without explain properly with relevant code no will can help you.

Comment: no i want to set response image data of server in 1st viewcontroller and the coming image is to set on second viewcontroller in collection view help me out